# Freeswitch "mod_verto" : Invalid Method, Missing Method or Permission Denied

Tags: freeswitch, mod-verto

I am working with mod_verto. I followed the following link https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_verto  
for the verto configuration. Also installed certificate on server and client side and added `<param name="jsonrpc-allowed-methods" value="verto"/>` to user directory. I am able to log in from web (verto client) to FreeSwitch but unable  to make a call, I'm getting following error:

> Invalid Method,Missing Method or Permission Denied mod_verto

Also added `<param name="jsonrpc-allowed-methods" value="verto"/>` but still I don't see any changes. I am a beginner in FreeSwitch.

Comment: please post the sip trace...

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have this param on or not.

From the directory `default.xml` in the default configs:

```
<param name="jsonrpc-allowed-methods" value="verto"/>
```

Comment: I already added  <param name="jsonrpc-allowed-methods" value="verto"/>

Comment: just paste all your configuration here